# AspectJ matching return type as interface with generics

Tags: aspectj

I'm trying to create an AspectJ Aspect to intercept the returning methods that has a generic interface.

This is my AspectJ

```
@AspectJ
public class MyAspect {

    @AfterReturning("execution(java.util.Collection+<mypackage.MyAbstractEntity+> mypackage.mvc.controllers..*.*(..))", returning = "list")
    public doStuff(JoinPoint j, Collection<MyAbstractEntity> list) {
    }
}
```

and this is my class that I want to weave into:

```
package mypackage.mvc.controller;

public class MyController {
    // MyEntity extends MyAbstractEntity
    public List<MyEntity> findAll() {
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved!

Put the "plus" after the generics definition ("plus" means "classes that extends it"):

```
java.util.Collection<mypackage.MyAbstractEntity+>+
```

And contract the "list" as "? extends":

```
public doStuff(JoinPoint j, Collection<? extends MyAbstractEntity> list) {
```

The code will look like this:

```
@AspectJ
public class MyAspect {

    @AfterReturning("execution(java.util.Collection<mypackage.MyAbstractEntity+>+ mypackage.mvc.controllers..*.*(..))", returning = "list")
    public doStuff(JoinPoint j, Collection<MyAbstractEntity> list) {
    }
}
```

Comment: That little plus sign isn't very well documented! Thank so much for this!

Comment: @Shaded "plus" means "classes that extends it", in case, Collection specializations