# Using generic types as return type for a pointcut

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I'm using Spring Boot to set up a REST API. I'll be making a bunch of `@RestController`s and want to set a pointcut on those methods that return a subtype of a specific abstract class I call `Model`. These controllers look something like this:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(...)
    public Person getAllPeople() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Where my `Person` class would look something like this:

```
public class Person extends Model {
    ...
}
```

So would it be possible to write advice that looks something like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ModelAspect {
    @AfterReturning(
        value = "execution(<T extends mypackages.Model> T mypackages.api.*.*(..))",
        returning = "model")
    public void doSomethingWithModel(Model model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Of course that won't work because the advice is not valid syntactically. In the reference documentation, I have only found information about generic parameters, not return types ([Spring AOP reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-params)). What I have now is this, but I think something like the example above would be a lot more efficient:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ModelAspect {
    @AfterReturning(
        value = "execution(* mypackages.api.*.*(..))",
        returning = "model")
    public void doSomething(Object model) {
        if (model instanceof Model)
            doSomethingWithModel((Model) model);
    }
}
```

My next question would be, is the same possible for those methods that return a `Collection` of suptypes of `Model`? Because the reference states that parameter types cannot be generic `Collection`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using + after your interface?

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ModelAspect {
    @AfterReturning(
        value = "execution(mypackages.Model+ mypackages.api.*.*(..))",
        returning = "model")
    public void doSomethingWithModel(Model model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You could try do not specify the return type. Based on the documentation it will be resolved by the type of the parameter used at the returning clause:

> A returning clause also restricts matching to only those method
>   executions that return a value of the specified type ( Object in this
>   case, which will match any return value).

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ModelAspect {
    @AfterReturning(
        value = "execution(* mypackages.api.*.*(..))",
        returning = "model")
    public void doSomethingWithModel(Model model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Have a look to the below link. It answers also your second question, about generic collections.

[Aspectj Matching Return Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669630/aspectj-matching-return-type-as-interface-with-generics)

---

Just for curiosity I have created a project for testing this and it started working for me straight forward. I can only think the path your pointcut is pointing to is wrong. Try with:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class ModelAspect {
    @AfterReturning(
        value = "execution(* mypackages.api..*(..))",
        returning = "model")
    public void doSomethingWithModel(Model model) {
        ...
    }
}
```

You can have a look to my project at: [spring-aspectj-interfaces](https://github.com/alfcope/spring-aspectj-interfaces)
There you will see different values for the pointcut (only one not commented, of course), all of them valid.

Comment: No luck. I did read about the "+" being used in class declarations and method parameters, but not in return types, maybe it's not (yet) supported there? I should note that my `Model` is not actually an interface but an abstract class, I'll change it in my question as well.

Comment: Still can't get that to work... I tried both with the `value` parameter and the `pointcut` parameter. No errors, the aspect's method is just never invoked. You do have to specify a return type when using "execution" advice btw, but it can be the wildcard `*`.

Comment: @delucasvb, Yes, it was a typo. When I said do not specify the return type I meant use asterisk. I have edited my answer.

Comment: It works!! Turns out I did have a bad path. I guess I have to look out for a tool that can help me with that. Maybe something with code completion

Comment: @alfcope How do find the `+` is valid for subclass? I cannot find anythings about it in the internet.

Comment: @Cnfn have a look to the "Subtype patterns" section here: https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html#type-patterns